# Adding Public groups to sharing rule via apex

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing

My question is How to add public groups to "CASE" sharing rule through APEX

```
 {

    Group g= [ select Id,name from group where name=:'kgroup'];
    
    Case c = new case();
    CaseShare cse = new CaseShare();
    cse.CaseId =c.id;
    cse.UserOrGroupId =g.id;
    cse.caseAccessLevel='Edit';
    
    Insert cse;
    
    }
```

I'm getting error like
REQUIRED_FIED_MISSING, Required fields are missing:[CaseId]:[CaseId]

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I feel like this might be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info), given the problems this might cause. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Can u please check the question again

Comment: You are instantiating a new case object  and then assigning its id, you have to query it or insert it first to get id of case

Comment: Now I'm not able to see that group in share settings

Answer (score 1):

Here we need first Create Case record then and it can share.

```
{
    Group g= [ select Id,name from group where name=:'kgroup'];
    //Create Case Record
    Case c = new case();
    c.Subject='Test Subject';
    c.Description = 'Test Desc';
    Insert c;

    // Share created record to group by creating record in share record
    CaseShare cse = new CaseShare();
    cse.CaseId =c.id;
    cse.UserOrGroupId =g.id;
    cse.caseAccessLevel='Edit';
    
    Insert cse;
    
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's working but I'm not able to see the public grp in front end(share settings) can u please share the output and please tell why it's(public group )not visible in frontend